# Knockout Subscribable / Pub / Sub not working?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, single-page-application, durandal

Following this guide: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html

I've attempted to implement pub/sub functionality in a Durandal application.  The structure of a durandal app gives me a shell.js model, which consumes other viewModels, such as "home.js".

In shell.js, I have the following code:

```
var postbox = new ko.subscribable();

ko.subscribable.fn.publishOn = function (topic) {
    this.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        postbox.notifySubscribers(newValue, topic);
    });

    return this; //support chaining
};

ko.subscribable.fn.subscribeTo = function (topic) {
    postbox.subscribe(this, null, topic);
    return this;  //support chaining
};

this.myObservable = ko.observable().subscribeTo("myTopic");
```

Then in my "home.js" I have the following:

```
this.myObservable = ko.observable("myValue").publishOn("myTopic");
```

However myObservable is always "undefined" in shell.js.

I couldn't figure out how to post only the relevant parts of my project on jsFiddle, so I just created a bare-minimum example here to demonstrate my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/75/

Here, I should be seeing both public and private name, but I'm just seeing the private name.  Why is the ".subscribeTo" not working here?  I'm in chrome, and I have cleared my cache.

**UPDATE:** I think it's because the "subscribeTo()" value only captures a value when the "publishOn()" value changes, but doesn't capture the value on load.  See this change:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/76/

Is there any way to make the "subscribeTo()" value get the initial value of the topic so this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added firebug lite to your fiddle and saved the view model instance to a variable so I could access it in firebug: http://jsfiddle.net/Gt5pp/

If you run `vm.privateName("test 2")` to update `privateName`, then both the PUBLIC and the PRIVATE are updated to `test 2` so it looks to be working fine.

As far as why your PUBLIC isn't `test` to start, I think its because the the observable is getting created and its value is getting set before the `publishOn` is registered so that very first value set isn't "heard."

Comment: Thanks man, I just found the same thing (see update).  Can you think of any way I can get the initial value to load as expected?

Comment: i would probably vote for creating the observable and setting the initial value in two steps: `this.myObservable = ko.observable().publishOn("myTopic")` and then `this.myObservable("myValue")`